# Transform 'long' data into 'wide' array using javascript

Tags: javascript, r, casting, google-visualization

In R, there is an extremely convenient way to transform 'long' data into 'wide', applying a function (like counting the number of occurrences) using `dcast` from the `{reshape2}` package. I would like to use a similar transformation in javascript. An R example (with [sample data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zvvdyf7iac1yvgz/so_question2.csv?dl=0)):

```
library(reshape2)
data.long = read.table("so_question2.csv", sep = "\t")

head(data.long)
# This is how a first few rows of the original data look like:
#    dpt    sem
# 15 Dpt.4  2014.1
# 16 Dpt.4  2014.1
# 17 Dpt.4  2014.1
# 18 Dpt.4  2014.1
# 19 Dpt.4  2014.1
# 20 Dpt.4  2014.1

data.wide = dcast(data, sem ~ dpt, length)

head(data.wide)
# This is how it looks like after the transformation; there are counts in columns now
#   sem        Dpt.1 Dpt.2 Dpt.3 Dpt.4
# 1 2012.1     0     0     0     8
# 2 2012.2     3     6     0    21
# 3 2013.1     3     4     0    29
# 4 2013.2     5     1     2    39
# 5 2014.1     5     3     7    39
```

Why do I need this: I'm learning to use Google Charts, and would like to be able to transform the data after [importing them](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#Google_Spreadsheets_as_a_Data_Source) from the spreadsheet. I know I could make the transformation in the spreadsheet itself; but it would be very inconvenient to clutter the spreadsheet with a large number of formulas. I would much prefer each chart to do its own transformation within its own script.

Comment: There's nothing like this in standard javascript, you'll need to write a dcast() implementation in JS if you want to use that transform.

Comment: Some library perhaps?

Comment: I don't know of any.   The concept of "melting" data frames is very R specific.   Relational database theory has something similar to "wide" vs. "long" data formats, but that doesn't help you...

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same problem! Here's a handy function for you.

```
// helper function
function addIfMissing(array, value) {
    var found = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        if(array[i] === value)
            return array;
    array.push(value);
    return array;
}

function restructure(input) {
    var output = [], headerX = [], headerY = [], xCoor, yCoor;

    // first create non-repeating headers
    headerX.push(input[0][0]);
    headerY.push(input[0][0]);
    for(var i = 1; i < input.length; i++)
        headerX = addIfMissing(headerX, input[i][0]), headerY = addIfMissing(headerY, input[i][1]);

    // put headers into output array
    for(var i = 0; i < headerX.length; i++)
        output.push([headerX[i]]);
    output[0] = headerY;

    // find correct headers on both axes and input data
    for(var i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
        for(var k = 1; k < headerX.length; k++)
            if(output[k][0] == input[i][0])
                xCoor = k;
        for(var j = 1; j < headerY.length; j++)
            if(output[0][j] == input[i][1])
                yCoor = j;
        output[xCoor][yCoor] = input[i][2];
    }

    return output;
}
```

And I tested it with this:

```
var input = [
    ['Season', 'Type', 'Number'],
    ['Winter', 'Sales', 1000],
    ['Winter', 'Expenses', 400],
    ['Winter', 'Profit', 200],
    ['Spring', 'Sales', 1170],
    ['Spring', 'Expenses', 460],
    ['Spring', 'Profit', 250],
    ['Summer', 'Sales', 660],
    ['Summer', 'Expenses', 1120],
    ['Summer', 'Profit', 300],
    ['Fall', 'Sales', 1030],
    ['Fall', 'Expenses', 540],
    ['Fall', 'Profit', 350]
];

var desiredOutput = [
    ['Season', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
    ['Winter', 1000, 400, 200],
    ['Spring', 1170, 460, 250],
    ['Summer', 660, 1120, 300],
    ['Fall', 1030, 540, 350]
];

var output = restructure(input);

if (JSON.stringify(output) == JSON.stringify(desiredOutput)) 
    alert("Pass");
```

[**Test example JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/crclayton/8v6975hb/20/)

[**And example of how I implemented it with google charts**](http://jsfiddle.net/crclayton/r67ega11/18/)

Comment: I was playing around with your solution, and I found an error:  if I remove 'Winter' 'Sales' and 'Profit' rows, I get a resulting output row for winter of: ["Winter",400].  I'd expect that the correct output would be ["Winter",null,400,null] or ["Winter", 0, 400, 0], but I think i'd go with the 'null' values to indicate the value for that category did not exist.

Comment: Update, playing around further: the order of the data matters. When I kept the 'type's together, if found all the different types and the only real problem is that the last element in the array for a given 'season' may not be set to 'null', but if you access the element in the array, you'll get null (or probably, undefined). would be ideal if all output rows had the same number of elements in it, null representing not exist.